# Increase volume with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the code below I want it to automatically increment up like this:
`(t, 30,33)` and `(t, 60,63)`, `(t, 90,93)` and so on it adds `30` units.

```
     ffmpeg -i in.mov -vcodec copy -af "volume=enable='between(t,30,33)':volume=0"out2.mov
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
-af "volume=enable='gte(t,30)*lt(mod(t,30),3)':volume=0"
```

Comment: Can you explain the parameters for me? Thank you so much

Comment: `lt(mod(t,30),3)` selects first 3 seconds of every 30 seconds, `gte(t,30)` starts selection from  t=30s, so that the first 3 seconds (0-3) aren't selected.